# What is the best way to test if an input is empty?

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have seen things like:

- `input.value == ''`
- `input.value == null`
- `input.value.length > 0`

Or combinations of these and others. But I suppose there is an optimal way, considering we're talking about a string, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a string with just spaces ;)

Comment: Note that an empty string evaluates to a boolean false, so `if('')` returns false.

Comment: The first one with three = instead of two (it's a bit faster: http://jsperf.com/2equals-vs-3equals/4). Null isn't a good idea because those two aren't the same type so one will be casted and getting length means getting one more property to do a test that would need the same time to be done. So the best way is: input.value === ""
But anyway, it's nothing in comparison with the time it takes to find the input in the DOM or anything else (so if you checked another way 100 times, you don't have to change :-° ).

Comment: @stand: True but if(variable) is exactly if(variable==true) so you better use === and therefore a test value which has the same type (in case you really want that millisecond :o ).

Comment: @xavierm02: What's a millisecond or two between friends? Though I feel compelled in the name of pedantry to point out that `if(variable===true)` has 7 more characters than `if(variable)` so your millisecond savings is countered by the longer download time. ;)

Comment: @stand: If you optimise you website that way too, you'll have some gzip function that'll replace ===true by a single character or something. So it's ok :-° And that only counts for the first load. After that, it's in the cache. (And 7 characters less won't make you win much more time. The HTTP request is long but the transfer itself for a so-called normal JavaScript file is kinda short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to be explicit and check for the value I actually want. So if I want to check for an empty string i prefer doing `input.value === ""` since value is always a string.

Answer (score 1):

I like `input.value.length > 0`. The `NULL` option should almost never trigger unless the object has no `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

personally i alway like to test with

```
input.value.match(/\S/);
```

Note that this will be true for empty value and for values containing only whitespace.

Of the methods you offered i would use the length property, although for an empty string it should be

```
input.value.length == 0
```

Comment: Rather input.value.search( /\S/ ) !== -1
http://jsperf.com/regex-test-methods (Yay, another ms won /o/)

Answer (score 1):

To determine an empty value you can use:  `if(getElementById('input').value)` or `if($('.inputBox').val())`

Using that conditional statement, both of these would evaluate to false:

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox" value="" />
<input type="text" id="inputBox" />
```

I like this method because it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it may depend on what you are accepting in the field.  Even though it may come in as a string you can still validate it for what it may be.

eg: if it is an email address you can perform a regular expression to see if it follows the form of an email.

The same goes with most fields.  This way you can be fairly confidant with the data you are receiving. Not just that it is not null.

For null checks I usually use .length > 0 for form objects.